# Progressive matrix of circles with crosses/circles on the border and geometric shapes in the center

Tags: pattern, progressive-matrix

[image: progressive matrix problem]

What is the solution to this problem?

Source: https://www.master-hr.com/what-you-need-to-know-about-a-cognitive-test/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is

> **Option 5 as it satisfies the pattern** 
> [image: the option that the op gave ofc]

Reasoning

> - Right off the top we can see that 3 combination exists for every
> surrounding symbol except the X 
>  - We also see that there are 3 combinations for every shape except the closed triangle. 
>  - That narrows it down to just options 4 and 5 
>  [image]

but

> There already exists a combination for the upright triangle
>  [image] 
>  hence cancelling option 4 out thus leaving us with just option 5 as the right answer.

Comment: Thanks! So the fact that the outside circles in the center figure are rotated by 45 degrees compared to the others has no meaning?

Comment: Nah its not that complicated, Sometimes its the simple answers that are right